# Issues setting "git init" on windows sub system

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-push

Running a sub system of linux - Ubuntu and when i try to "git init" in order to start pushing to github i get the following error

```
error: chmod on /mnt/c/Users/skywalker/dev/flatiron/projects/StarwarsCLI/.git/config.lock failed: 
Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
```

I was told to run

```
Open your Windows Defender Security Center
Go to Home
Click and open "Virus and Threat protection"
Click and open "Virus and threat Protection Setting"
Click and open "Manage Controlled folder access" in "Controlled folder access"option
Turn the "Controlled Folder access" OFF
Run "Git init" from cmd. DONE!
```

With no resolution -

Any advice ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and this worked for me:

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```